# soap with attachments in dot.net3.5

Tags: wcf, soap, httpwebrequest

how do I post a soap wit attachments in C# .net3.5? I am new to .net and i read somewhere that the framework does not handle SWA, its all done via WCF services.Does anyone have sample code of how to post a SOAP with attachments? thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [codeplex project for SWA support in WCF](http://wcfswaencoder.codeplex.com/).

Btw. it is the first link in Google if you just search for WCF SWA!!!